# Recaptcha Rails 3.0 Error Recaptcha::Verify::Net

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added the recaptcha gem to my gem file like so:

```
gem "recaptcha", "~> 0.3.1", :require => 'recaptcha/rails'
```

I then created recaptcha.rb with my public and private key in initializers.

In my controller for create an account on my app I have the following code:

```
def create
@account = Account.new(params[:account])
if verify_recaptcha(:model => @account, :message => 'Captcha response is incorrect') && @account.save
```

When I hit the submit button for creating an account I get the following error:

Recaptcha::RecaptchaError in AccountsController#create

uninitialized constant Recaptcha::Verify::Net

Anyone know what the problem is?

Thank you,

Brian

Answer (score 1):

Answer: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/issues/7